# Grunt copy missing files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

For the last few days my `grunt copy` task is missing out some files. The task itself is the unedited task from SailsJS:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.config.set('copy', {
        dev: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: './assets',
                src: ['**/*.!(coffee|less|scss|sass|js)'],
                dest: '.tmp/public'
            }]
        },
        build: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/public',
                src: ['**/*'],
                dest: 'www'
            }]
        }
    });

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
};
```

I'm using Bower for dependencies within my `assets` folder which are copied to `.tmp/public` by Grunt.

Some facts:

- it's always the same files which are missing (`lib/marked.js`, `angular-elastic/elastic.js`, `angular-ui-select/dist/select.js`, `angular-slugify/angular-slugify.js`)
- it worked for quite some time - I didn't change anything in the task, just in the `assets` (but not in the `vendor`) folder.
- `grunt copy --verbose` also doesn't list these files.
- OS is win10.

Comment: If you change `src` to `['**/*']` what happens?

Comment: You are excluding .js extensions in the exclusion block: !(coffee|less|scss|sass|js). If you want to copy .js files remove js from that block => !(coffee|less|scss|sass)